# Make-Life-Easier App for PHP Programming

Tags: php, text-editors

Is there such an app out there that will allow me to see the parsing of a PHP script (or directory of files) in real time?

Thinking of the process of going through line by line of code as a movie, I dream of fast forwarding and backward "frame-by-frame" (in this case - line-by-line). I see an advantage of doing this as now I don't have to worry about opening another file if it is included, scrutinising (or using the Find) to a function definition somewhere in the big script in order to see what  don't have to worry if a variable might have been changed somewhere in an included file. Instead, I simply click on "Next line" and "previous line" and the app will just bring me to the next parsed line (not actual line).

At the same time, I visualise a couple of panels:
(1) the variable panel tracks - as I go line by line - what data has been assigned to it, and whether/how it changes
(2) constant panel - tracks which constants get defined
etc.

Where can I find such?

Comment: you mean you want a PHP debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, your description is rather vague, and, maybe this question should really be asked on the Software Recommendations forum.  But, as Rowland surmises, maybe you're looking for a debugger.  I'll assume that's the case and save you the trouble from posting once again on another board.  I would suggest you look at [PHPEd](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm).  It's an integrated IDE and debugger for PHP.  It's relatively inexpensive and provides lots of useful features.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Eclipse PHP](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), a very comfortable IDE for PHP.